# Get list of groups from javascript regex object

Tags: javascript, regex

It's possible to get list of group items from regex object?
For example, i have this regex:

```
var someRegex = /hello\s(.*?), i have (\d+) friends! (?:Bye)/;
```

I want to be able to get:

```
['(.*?)', '(\\d+)'];
```

(Note that i don't want to get the 'Bye' group because it has '?:' mark..)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\((?!\?:)[^(]*\)
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/bN8dL3/7

```
var re = /\((?!\?:)[^(]*\)/gi;
var str = 'hello\s(.*?), i have (\d+) friends! (?:Bye)';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
re.lastIndex++;
}
// View your result using the m-variable.
// eg m[0] etc.
}
```